# deploy statefulset on kubernetes with local pv: 2 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Background:
kubernets cluster: 1.18
3 nodes:

- host_master
- host_node1
- host_node2

`master with taint: node-role.kubernetes.io/master:Noschedule`

My case:

create dir on node1: `/data/oss0`; `/data/oss1`;
create dir on node2: `/data/oss2`; `/data/oss3`;

create pv/pvc with local volume

```yaml
# define local pv/pvc
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-oss-0
  labels:
    pvname: local-oss-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-oss
  local:
    path: /data/oss0
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - host_node1
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-oss-minio-test-0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: local-oss
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pvname: local-oss-0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-oss-1
  labels:
    pvname: local-oss-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-oss
  local:
    path: /data/oss1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - host_node1
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-oss-minio-test-1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: local-oss
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pvname: local-oss-1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-oss-2
  labels:
    pvname: local-oss-2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-oss
  local:
    path: /data/oss2
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - host_node2
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-oss-minio-test-2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: local-oss
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pvname: local-oss-2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-oss-3
  labels:
    pvname: local-oss-3
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-oss
  local:
    path: /data/oss3
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - host_node2
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-oss-minio-test-3
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: local-oss
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pvname: local-oss-3
```

As U see, create 4 pvcs, that's name match the statefulSet dynamic pvc, pvcname-{container-name}-{ordinal}

when apply a statefulSet with 4 replicates got error: **Warning  FailedScheduling  82s (x7 over 8m37s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.**

Some body can help me know, why?

2 nodes can not carry 4 replicates StatefulSet?
or just local pvc cannot use it as that?

Comment: Can you provide more information on your deployment like are you deploying one statefulset on one node and the second stateful set on another or using the two nodes commonly for both the statefulsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: `nodeAffinity` config conflict. The `hostname` in linux with a capital letter , but in Kubernetes is lowercase.